# Can i save my search history in Zathura (pdf viewer)?

Tags: pdf, search, indexing

By default, Zathura doesn't store the index of all words that a file contains, and i wish it did that for every file in which i've made at least one search.
If that's not clear, when i open a PDF for the first time and search for, per example, "energy", Zathura takes a while to scan all the file and then return me the result of my query. But then, when i try to make another search, let's say, for "fire", it returns its first occurrence immediately, as it keeps the index of the words in the file while it isn't closed.
The problem is that when i close the PDF and then open it again to do another search, it scans the whole file once more, taking some seconds to give me the result.

I've thought that setting to **false** the option described in the manual as *abort-clear-search*, which describes its function as "Defines if the search results should be cleared on abort", would keep this query index stored in some file so that when i opened some PDF for the second time after doing a research on it, Zathura wouldn't have to scan through it again, but it didn't make any difference.
Is there any native or even alternative way to keep these indexes? Should this option work as i expected?